# Can send() become non-blocking automatically?

Tags: c++, winsock, send

Do I have to wait for signals with select() in order to send something in non-blocking sockets ? What if I have always have something to send and then I call send() function ? I mean, everytime i call send(), there is definitely some data to send with fixed length. Does it mean that send will not block ?

Comment: I actually meant that : I have defined some non-blocking sockets. I have definitely something to send. Then I call send(), is it guaranteed to send ?

Comment: No. It is guaranteed to *not* block. If it cannot send (for example, if the send buffer is full), then it will return an error, immediately.

Comment: that's the answer i have been looking for, great. thanks

Comment: Okay then, putting that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `send` will never block on a non-blocking socket. If the data could not be sent (for example if the send buffer is full), then `send` will return immediately with a value of `SOCKET_ERROR`.

Any call that would block is signaled by an error code of `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` (by calling  `WSAGetLastError`).

The same is true for a call to `receive`, if there is no data in the receive buffer, the call still returns immediately, with an error.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the protocol. With regular blocking TCP socket `send()` might block since in-kernel socket buffer might be full. UDP, on the other hand, will either push the packet down the stack, or discard it if it's too big, without blocking.

#### Edit 0:

Ok, thanks to @Cicada, I see I missed that we are talking about non-blocking sockets, so ...

It still depends on the protocol - with UDP your packet is either sent or discarded; with TCP you try to send at the time you have data, and if you get `EWOULDBLOCK` you register your socket with `select()`/`poll()`, and re-try sending when kernel tells you the socket is writable again.

Comment: Yes, in the case of regular, blocking sockets. (See OP's first comment just under his question).